# How to get the private key of my azure web app

Tags: ssl-certificate, azure

I have inherited an Azure Web App and I would like to secure it with SSL.

Following the official Microsoft Guide [(here)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/#1-get-an-ssl-certificate) I completed steps 1 - 5 of   **"1. Get an SSL certificate"**

Therefore I have :

- a CSR - File
- uploaded the CSR to my ssl-vendor (in my case godaddy)
- downloaded the certificate for Windows IIS (.crt & .p7b)

But now I run into troubles.

6. I jumped that step because I have an crt not cer
7. Worked like a charm
8. I found the certificate in "other users > certificates"

And now with **Step 9** the problems begin.
I never get prompted if I want to export the private key and the `.pfx` option is greyed out.

[image]

As it seems, it is greyed out because I do not have the private key.

Where do I get the private-key-file from my azure-app?
Or do I understand something awfully wrong here?

Comment: You need to finish following the guide.

Comment: I updated my question to provide more information

Comment: You skipped step 6, you need to do that.

Comment: I don't have a `cer` file. As stated above the zip file of godaddy only contains `crt` and `p7b`

Comment: The crt file _is_ the certificate!

Comment: But running `certreq -accept -user mycert.crt` with my `crt` throws me an error `0x80092004 - CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: You need to do this on the same machine that you generated the CSR.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32100/discussion-between-altoyr-and-michael-hampton).